# "Connection Reset by Peer" if server calls close() immediately after write()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix, android-ndk

I have a `AF_INET`/`SOCK_STREAM` server written in C running on Android/Linux which looks more ore less like this:

```
...
for (;;) {
    client = accept(...);
    read(client, &message, sizeof(message));
    response = process(&message);
    write(client, response, sizeof(*response));
    close(client);
}
```

As far as I know, the call to close should not terminate the connection to the client immediately, but it apparently does: The client reports "Connection Reset by Peer" before it has had a chance to read the server's response.

If I insert a delay between `write()` and `close()` the client can read the response as expected.

I got a hint that it might have to do with the `SO_LINGER` option, but I checked it's value and both members of struct linger (`l_onoff`, `l_linger`) have a value of zero.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Stevens describes a configuration in which this can happen, but it depends on the client sending more data after the server has called close() (after the client should “know” that the connection is being closed).  UNP 2nd ed s5.12.

Try tcpdumping the conversation to find out what’s really going on.  If there's any possibility that a “clever” gateway (e.g. NAT) is between the two endpoints, tcpdump both ends and look for discrepancies.

Comment: I suspect this is what's happening. +1 for catching that possibility and for good advice on how to debug the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Connection gets reset when you call `close()` on connection with data being sent. Specially for this case the sequence of `shutdown()` with SHUT_WR flag and then blocking `read()` is used.

Shutting down the writing end of the socket sends FIN and returns immediately, and the said read() blocks and returns 0 as soon as your peer replies with FIN in due turn. Basically, this is what you need in place of the delay between `write()` and `close()` you are talking about.

You do not need do anything with `linger` options in this case, leave it all to default.

Answer (score 0):

SO_LINGER should be set (i.e. set to 1 not 0) if you want queued data to be sent before a close is effected.

> SO_LINGER
>       Lingers on a close() if data is present. This option controls the
>   action taken when unsent messages
>   queue on a socket and close() is
>   performed. If SO_LINGER is set, the
>   system shall block the calling thread
>   during close() until it can transmit
>   the data or until the time expires. If
>   SO_LINGER is not specified, and
>   close() is issued, the system handles
>   the call in a way that allows the
>   calling thread to continue as quickly
>   as possible. This option takes a
>   linger structure, as defined in the
>    header, to specify the
>   state of the option and linger
>   interval.

Comment: This shouldn't affect the client/network, just make the server block during the linger rather than continuing.